# CAPL: On Message Not Recognizing Database

Tags: capl

Programming for CANalyzer in the Vector CAPL Browser, I can start typing "on message CAN4..." and it will auto complete things for me. I can see the messages. But after selecting a message, it always yells at me with "Expecting message name or identifier. Database missing?" as if it has no idea what I just put in even though it helped me put it there. What is the proper format for this? Is it different since I'm using ARXML instead of DBC? Is it just not compatible?

```
on message CAN4::Something_PDU // Auto-completes this but gives the error
{ 
}

on message CAN4.Something_PDU // Never auto-completes this and also doesn't work
{
}

on message CAN4::Something_PDU::Something_Auth // Auto-completes but not sure that's what I want and also doesn't compile with same error.
{
}
```

What is the right way and/or why doesn't it recognize the database despite its obvious ability to auto-complete? So confused!

Comment: How does your measurement setup look like? Is a database assigned to channel `CAN4`?

Comment: @M. Spiller -- Yes indeed! Specifically an ARXML file.

Answer (score 0):

I just faced a comparable issue when trying to get called by incoming ethernet signals. They are also defined in an `*.arxml`, in my case. However, the behaviour of the Vector CAPL-Browser was exactly the same as you described.

I figured out that replacing `on message` with `on signal` does the trick and the script can get compiled:

```
on signal Something_Signal  // autocompletion works and compiles
{
}

on signal Eth1::Something_Signal // autocompletion doesn't work but compiles
{ 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
on pdu Something_PDU
```

Answer (score -1):

there is another way to do this:
 goto Windows symbols on the right panel in CAPL Editor >
try to find Something_PDU > drag and drop PDU_Name on your Code after on message 
**the CAPL event on message should be use with *name***

try use

```
on message Something_PDU
```

instead of

```
on message CAN4.Something_PDU
```